# Appending to array while iterating over it

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script that loops through an array of entries and adds a new day object with a date if that date is not already in the date list.

```
entryList = [aDate,anotherDate,fooDate]
history = [aDate]

for entry in entryList:
  for day in history[:]:
    if day.date == entry.date:
      break
    else:
      dayEntry = dayEntry()
      dayEntry.date = entry.date
      history.insert(0,dayEntry)
      break
```

according to this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html it should work, but I'm missing something.

thanks--

Comment: Using a `dict` instead of a `list` seems better suited here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to append to `history` the entries in `entryList` but only the first one for a given date?

I think this is a case for `not any()`.

```
for entry in entryList:
    if not any(day.date == entry.date for day in history):
        dayEntry = dayEntry()
        dayEntry.date = entry.date
        history.insert(0,dayEntry)
```

`not any(day.date == entry.date for day in history)`

reads as: there isn't a day in history with this entry's date.

If the history is permitted to be a dictionary, where the keys are the entries' dates, rather than a list:

```
for entry in entryList:
    if entry.date not in history:
        dayEntry = dayEntry()
        dayEntry.date = entry.date
        history[dayEntry.date] = dayEntry
```

Another option is to use a set along with the two lists:

```
dates = set()
for entry in history:
   dates.add(entry.date)

for entry in entryList:
    if entry.date not in dates:
        dayEntry = dayEntry()
        dayEntry.date = entry.date
        history.insert(0,dayEntry)
        dates.add(entry.date)
```

Comment: @40Hz Probably you were getting stuck in an infinite loop in the original code because if you insert in the beginning of a list you are iterating over, you have the same element next iteration.

Comment: @Dan D. YOU ARE A SAINT.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work as is:

```
>>> entrylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> history = [1,]
>>> for e in entrylist:
...     for d in history[:]:
...         if d == e:
...             break;
...         else:
...             history.insert(0, e)
...             break;
...
>>> entrylist
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> history
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about having duplicates.  My code is the OP code, just with the objects replaced with simple integers.   I just typed it in to the interpreter, and this is the result.